# comparing 2 different xsd

Tags: xsd, comparison

I have 2 different xsd for same request. one is latest version while the other one is older version. I want to compare 2 xsd's.

I used Liquid XML tool to generate the XML but the generated xml tells that the 2 xsds are TOTALLY different, which i believe is not possible. either my approach is wrong or the xsds are really different.

could you guys suggest me the best practice to compare 2 xsds?

Answer (score 1):

[QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com/) has an XSD-aware compare feature, that is part of the XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) module; Being XSD-aware, it sometimes surprises people that are rather used to file-based comparison, be that compare text or XML-aware.

QTAssistant doesn’t actually compare XSD files; instead, it compares “compiled” sets of XSD files. So, if someone decides to simply split an XSD in two files, linked together using an <xsd:include/>, and then compare these two sets, the result would come back as “identical”. A good example is the [ACORD](http://www.acord.org/Pages/default.aspx) standard, which changed its way of releasing XSDs. Below is an example showing 2.21 vs. 2.26 releases organized as sets in QTAssistant...

[image: ACORD Collections]

... and the relationships between files in release 2.21 (uses <xsd:include/>s).

[image: File relationships in ACORD 2.21]

Another example: if a minOccurs or maxOccurs=”1” attribute is removed between versions, this difference won’t be flagged since these 1s are default values anyway…

Other interesting feature is the granularity provided by the diff report...

[image: Diff report]

In addition to have the result available at the level of each XSD component, it is also split in two: one result, ***Status***, for whether the schema component was materially changed directly (below the LastRaceDate was "replaced" with a choice between LastRaceDate and LastDatePartialDate)...

[image: Directly modified XSD component]

... and another, ***Extended Status***, that considers an impact analysis based on dependencies (below the attribute was changed from mandatory to optional).

[image: Dependency modified]

The report can be exported, for further integration with other tools.

Answer (score 0):

[Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) has an XML comparison tool.

Alternatively, you can pretty-print both XSDs and compare them using diff or [TortoiseMerge](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html) or something like that.

Comment: the definition of elements could be on top or at the bottom. the order of defining the elementds doesn't matter .. so just comparing wouldnt help